# Error Converting DateTime using format

Tags: filehelpers, type-conversion

I get the following error when trying to import a CSV file.

Error Converting '2007/01/02' to type: 'DateTime'.  Using the format: 'yyyy/MM/dd'

I have set the class like this:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy/MM/dd")]
public DateTime PriceDate;
```

Any idea why that could be, since the format matches - it is the second of Jan 2007?

When I change the date format to 2007.01.02 then Filehelpers parses perfectly.

I use V 3.1.5.0

Thanks

Comment: I will try to review it on weekend, by the time, you can use public string PriceDate; and convert to DateTime in your app, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the mask to:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy/M/d")]
public DateTime PriceDate;
```

Click on the 'Converters' tab in [this link](http://www.filehelpers.net/mustread/) to learn more about a handful of datatypes available, such as numeric and dates.